# Xcode fails to build the app

Tags: ios, xcode6

The build was working and suddenly things went wrong. It seems the only thing causing this error is Parse library and I deleted it from framework folder and added it again but nothing seems to get past the below shown 4 errors.

I also went to Build Settings and deleted Parse from framework paths, search paths, and anywhere else it should exist in the page. Still no luck. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Bolts.framework` to your project that comes along with the Parse SDK.